# Calculated Field

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a simple pivot table which will tell me how many community residents reported a particular problem, and what percentage of them reported each problem type.  I have a data set with name, and then columns for each type of problem.  Here's an small sample of the data set:

[image]

I have created a pivot table which sums each of these columns and also provides me the total number of people who reported any type of problem at all.  Here's what I have:

[image]

I want to add a second column to this pivot table that gives the percent of times each problem type was reported.  Sounds simple, but because of the structure of the original data set, I can't figure out how to do it.  I can set up formulas outside of the Pivot Table which reference the table, but in doing so I forfeit the ability to graph the percentages on a pivot chart.  Any ideas how to create a calculated field for this pivot table?

Just to be clear, what I want is something like this, except all contained in the structure of the pivot table:

[image]

Edit: I've changed the example of the data set.  Here's an explanation of the pivot table.  The values under the "# Reporting Issue" column are counts of all the 1's under each corresponding column in the data set.  This meant that I had to add each row to the pivot table independently, as you can see here:

[image]

I'm open to the idea that I need to change the formatting of the data set, but I'm not sure of the best way to do it.  This was set up initially because it allowed for easy compilation into a data table, but Pivot Tables seem to be a different story.

Hopefully this edit clarifies things.

Comment: Could you supply some actual data as it is laid out in the sheet. You can use a [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)to format properly. It is hard for me to see how you arrived at your pivot layout from the top image data layout.

Comment: I've edited the original question.  Hopefully that helps

Comment: So #Reporting Issue column is a count? Is it the yes? Where is your yes/no split? Feels like you should be able to do something like right click > summarize as percentage of grand total

Comment: It's like... your data is already pivoted. And now you are pivoting it again. So in your actual excel pivot table you are unpivoting, then aggregating it. It's like pivot inception.

Comment: ^^ Like the Count of Did this person in the rows bit is freaking me out

Comment: I can't simply summarize as a percentage of grand total, because people report multiple issues.  I have to divide the number who reported each issue by the count of people who reported issues.  

Apologies for not understanding pivot tables very well, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm reading some stuff now, and I'm going to have to completely restructure my source data.

Comment: we are not strictly supposed to do file sharing me thinks but can you share a file with dummy data in, in the same format ? Macro free workbook to https://uploadfiles.io/ or some such?

Comment: Essentially, you will normally want a flat file format for your data. And this is the seminal work http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html Download here https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot your data  so that you turn it into a Flat File...something that the PivotTable can consume properly.

The easiest way is to use something called PowerQuery, which is baked in to Excel 2016 but available as a free addin from Microsoft for any other versions. Google PowerQuery Unpivot and you will turn up hundreds of tutorials, such as [this one from my good pal Chandoo](https://chandoo.org/wp/2015/09/29/unpivot-data-with-power-query/) . PowerQuery looks slightly daunting at first to a first time user, but it is freakin easy once you get your head around how to use it. PQ is by far the best addition to Excel in years. PowerPivot being a close second.

If you can't install PowerQuery, then you can use your current data structure to make a 'staging pivot', and then drag the Values label that will appear in the Columns area to the bottom of the ROWS pane, like in this excerpt from a book I'm writing:

[image]

Note that my Year categories are equivalent to your Issues categories.

That will emulate the flat file layout you’re after. All you need to do then is turn this intermediate PivotTable back into a normal range, change that Values heading to Issue, and add a Count heading and you’ve got the flat file you need to build a useable PivotTable.

You can also use VBA. Google Unpivot VBA and turn up hundreds of results, including [this blazingly fast code](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/) I posted some time back. (Look for the code under the —Update 26 November 2013— heading.)

You can also use the [DoubleClick extraction trick](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/transposing-a-dataset-with-a-pivottable/).